# SQL - combined results of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add rows from table alpha which has the same value in column a as table beta.

For example:

table alpha:

```
a b c
1 2 6
1 4 5
2 6 7
2 4 9
6 4 3
6 3 2
```

table beta:

```
a y z
1 2 3
2 4 5
6 4 9
8 5 3
9 4 3
```

requested ruselt:

for example where a=2:

```
a ? ?
2 4 5
2 6 7
2 4 9
```

and where a=6:

```
a ? ?
6 4 9
6 4 3
6 3 2
```

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when a=2, how did you calculate the 1st line & same question when a=6, how did you calculate 1st line?I want to know, what is the formula to calculate the 1st line...

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from table alpha where id a=2 
union all
select * from table beta where id a=2
```

Comment: yes union all is working! but is there any way somehow to mark the additional rows?

Comment: if you don't want to use union then you can do it using a temporary table.CREATE TABLE temp_ids(ID INT);

INSERT INTO temp_ids SELECT ID FROM a;
INSERT INTO temp_ids SELECT ID FROM b;

SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM temp_ids;

Comment: This method is preferable in MySQL because MySQL materializes subqueries (in almost any other database, the two should be the same).

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achive the result you want by using a `union` in a derived table and then filter the result:

```
select * 
from (
    select a,b,c from alpha
    union all
    select a,y,z from beta
) u
where a = 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can label the result from the table they are got using below Sql

```
select a,b,c, 'tableAlpha' from alpha where a = 2
union all
select a,b,c, 'tableBetha' from  betha where a = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to insert those rows from Alpha to Beta with same values in column a. You may try CTE for this.

```
;WITH cte_getData
AS
(
SELECT A.a,b,c FROM 
Alpha A
INNER JOIN 
Beta B
ON A.a = B.a)
INSERT INTO Beta
SELECT * FROM cte_getData
```

Although this does not check if that row already exists in Beta or not. If you want to cover that case as well, you may use LEFT OUTER JOIN and check for A.a = NULL in CTE.